# How to redirect ip:port to subdomain in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect ip:port requests to a specific subdomain like following :

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 > app1.nilux.eu
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8099 > app2.nilux.eu
```

**edit :** I currently use this config :

```
ssl_certificate /crt/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /crt/ssl.key;

server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        return 301 $scheme://nilux.eu$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name nilux.eu www.nilux.eu;
        ssl on;

        return 404;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name app1.nilux.eu www.app1.nilux.eu;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name app2.nilux.eu www.app2.nilux.eu;
        ssl on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8099;
        }
}
```

But dont know how to redirect ip:port resquests.

Comment: What process is listening to port 8099? If that is an application server, you should firewall the port from outside, or make the app server bind only to localhost interface, so that it is not reachable from outside. There is no point in having any public access to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there!

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        return 301 $scheme://my.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

And the same for the other, but changing the port:

```
server {
        listen 8099;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        return 301 $scheme://other.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Basically you tell Nginx in which port to listen.

By default, HTTP port is 80, so, the default in nginx is **listen 80**;

But, if you wanna enter the site by other port, you just change the **listen** directive to another port.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the port in your server configuration.

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name 192.168.0.1;
  return 301 $scheme://nilux.eu$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 8099;
  server_name 192.168.0.1;
  return 301 $scheme://subdomain.nilux.eu$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Get the following issue : bind() to 0.0.0.0:8099 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: I forgot to report 8099 port is used in another server block in a proxy_pass directive.

Comment: You can only bind a port to one listener. You might be able to have Nginx listen and pass requests on to that application, but it depends what it is. Please edit your question to include all relevant details.

Comment: proxy_pass is not a listener. Try what I suggested. If it works please mark the question answered, if not please edit your question to say why not, give applicable information such as logs and curls, and comment here so I see it.